# Independent Event Probability Problem

Tags: probability

[image: Probability problem.]

I honestly do not now how to approach any of the parts, especially $(b)$ and $(c)$.

For part $(a)$, it seems like the way to approach the question would be to find the equation giving the probability that $1, 2, 3...$ classes are flagged, and then using it for the entire problem.

I apologize that I did not give a better attempt at an answer, but I have spent some time researching an approach, and I have not been able to find it.

**Also:** APS stands Atlanta Public Schools, and this came out of the recent standardized cheating scandal.

Comment: Have you been introduced to the binomial distribution?

Comment: Like this? $\dfrac{N!}{x!(N-x)!}  \pi^x(1-\pi)^{N-x}$ Is it as simple as plugging in the numbers and solving? I assumed there was another step here.

Comment: If that is the case, why does the problem say that I should not have factorials in the answer?

Comment: That is the case and the text says this because they want you to identify the (quite simple) binomial coefficient involved in this case.

Comment: It would be $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{1480}{1}$ then, right? But that is also not allowed in the problem.

Comment: Yes, but once again, **this** binomial coefficient is just 1480--which is probably "allowed".

Comment: So it's a scandal that's in every newspaper on Earth when the lowest-ranking teachers cheat, but when far higher-ranking people who have Ph.D.'s in mathematics devote decades of their careers to lying to students about the subject and who are heads of mathematics departments at respected universities, they are given every kind of respect and esteem.  The cheating in Atlanta is their fault. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of the binomial distribution the answer to (a) is
$$
p=1480\cdot\frac1{740}\cdot\left(1-\frac1{740}\right)^{1479}=2\cdot\left(\frac{739}{740}\right)^{1479}.
$$
This is the exact value but everybody would compute it using the approximation 
$$
\left(1-\frac1x\right)^x\approx\mathrm e^{-1},
$$
when $x$ is large, which yields in this case
$$
p\approx2\cdot\mathrm e^{-1479/740}\approx2\cdot\mathrm e^{-2}.
$$
...Which indicates that Poisson distributions are lurking in the background here.